# Exception as e. The e is not visible in the debugger

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Python 3.6**

```
def get_results(drv):
    try:
        table_element = WebDriverWait(drv,60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "tbody")))
    except TimeoutException as e:
        raise TimeoutException(e.message)
```

Screen shot: https://b.radikal.ru/b05/1810/52/65f03791c2e2.png

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/PoiskOptim/keyword_stuffing.py", line 56, in get_results
        table_element = WebDriverWait(drv, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "tbody")))
      File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/PoiskOptim/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
        raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:


    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/michael/Documents/pycharm-community-2018.2.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
        main()
      File "/home/michael/Documents/pycharm-community-2018.2.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
        globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
      File "/home/michael/Documents/pycharm-community-2018.2.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
        pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
      File "/home/michael/Documents/pycharm-community-2018.2.3/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
        exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
      File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/PoiskOptim/main.py", line 14, in <module>
        funcs[choice]()
      File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/PoiskOptim/keyword_stuffing.py", line 141, in keyword_stuffing
        parse_all(phrases)
      File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/PoiskOptim/keyword_stuffing.py", line 134, in parse_all
        handle_chunks(drv, phrases)
      File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/PoiskOptim/keyword_stuffing.py", line 81, in handle_chunks
        get_results(drv)
      File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/PoiskOptim/keyword_stuffing.py", line 58, in get_results
        raise TimeoutException(e.message)
    AttributeError: 'TimeoutException' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Could you help me understand what is going on here. I set TimeoutException as e. Well, I hoped that e would be at least visible in the debugger. But  no. There is no e in the context.

*Added later* 
The question is: **Why there is no e in the context**?

Comment: Why are you catching a `TimeoutException` just to raise another `TimeoutException` ???

Comment: bruno desthuilliers, really I do. It is called exception forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty obvious. You try to access the `message` attribute of your `e` variable which happens to be an object of type `TimeoutException`. In Python3 an Exception object does not have a `message` attribute anymore. If you want to print the exception message just use `str(e)`.

Comment: or use `e.args[0]`

Comment: MrLeeh and  bruno desthuilliers, thank you for your efforts. But the question is not about that. There is no e at all in the context. This is what troubles me. I edited the initial question.

Comment: What debugger are you using? Probably your script breaks at the wrong position and you already left the context of the `try-except` black. Try setting a breakpoint inside your except block then you should see your `e`.